# How to access an object in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I wrote this code

```
var enemies:Object = new Object();
//                HP  MP  ATK  DEF  MATK   MDEF  AGI  LUCK
enemies.Goblin = [40, 20,  6,   6,    3,     3,   4,   1];
```

which contains those stats for the goblin and I created a function that should take the stats from enemies.Goblin and put them in some variables but it won't work.

```
function createEnemy(enemyName:String):void {

e_hp = enemies.enemyName[0];
e_mp = enemies.enemyName[1];
e_atk = enemies.enemyName[2];
e_def = enemies.enemyName[3];
e_matk = enemies.enemyName[4];
e_mdef = enemies.enemyName[5];
e_agi = enemies.enemyName[6];
e_luck = enemies.enemyName[7];

}
```

This is the output error when the createEnemy function is executed: *TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object "enemies" does not have "enemyName" property.
Try this:

```
enemies[enemyName][0]
enemies[enemyName][1]
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer had been given but what are you doing is a wrong way to do. Accessing properties by index is asking for trouble in a very near future.

It is better to do with classes but since you're using objects, I will try use objects too:

```
var goblin_stats:Object = { hp:40, mp:20, atk:6, def:6 }; // and so on
var elf_stats:Object = { hp:35, mp:30, atk:8, def:4 }; // and so on
...
// add as much characters as needed
```

Now I believe you just want to create a fresh goblin based on goblin stats. Just pass the stats to the createEnemy function:

```
createEnemy(goblin_stats);

function createEnemy(stats:Object):void {
    e_hp = stats.hp;
    e_mp = stats.mp;
    // and so on
}
```

or better:

```
function createEnemy(stats:Object):void {
    for (var property:String in stats) e_stats[property] = stats[property];
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me why accessing properties by index might create troubles in the future?

Comment: It is much easier to remember them as "hp", "mp" etc. instead of 1,2,etc. When your code becomes more complex, you will want to add or remove some properties. After that you will want to re-enumerate them. These indexes will need to be changed multiple times and the code will become unmanageable. Think in a way that adding or removing a property would not require change in the code for other properties. If you add or remove property "hp" it will not affect property "mp" and any other properties. If you remove property 1, it will affect all properties after 1 - their indexes will change. See?

Answer (score 0):

Store objects (everything) in arrays for easy referencing.  Here are the key code:

```
var aEnemies:Array = new Array();
var mcEnemy:Object = new Object();

mcEnemy.iHP = 40;  //  set iHP property to 40

aEnemies.push(mcEnemy);  //  add enemy to array of enemies

trace("enemy 0's HP: " + aEnemies[0].iHP);
```